# c++ Clarification with String manipulation

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am not a c++ developper and I need to convert some code to vb.net

I found this

```
_tcslwr_s
```

which I don't even know if it is a type or a function (method).It is used in:

```
    _bstr_t _rbstProcessName
    TCHAR* ptcProcessName = static_cast<TCHAR*>(_rbstProcessName);
    _tcslwr_s(ptcProcessName, _rbstProcessName.length() + 1);
```

I know that `_tcslwr_s` is from a `#define` in `tchar.h`, a VS frameWork system file.

I would apreciate a short explanation of what is a `#define` and, in this case, what is `_tcslwr_s`

Thanks a lot in advance!

#### Edit

With the help of the comments now I know what is a define. Serching the code I found that `_tcslwr_s` define `_wcslwr_s`. The only two lines with this in it are in `string.h` and are:

```
_Check_return_wat_ _CRTIMP errno_t __cdecl _wcslwr_s(_Inout_z_cap_(_SizeInWords) wchar_t * _Str, _In_ size_t _SizeInWords);
__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_0(errno_t, _wcslwr_s, _Deref_prepost_z_ wchar_t, _String)
```

At this point I can't read anything.. What I am suposed to do to know what is going on with my two strings from the beginning (`_rbstProcessName` and `ptcProcessName`) ?

Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a macro.  You need to look in tchar.h to see how it's defined.  VB has no equivalent to #define macros - you will need to write an equivalent VB method, but you need to examine the original #define.

Comment: #define is macro, the purpose is basically for replacement.
For example, #define MAX 10000, when you see MAX in your code, compiler with replace it with 10000.

You can also define functions with #define. So both cases could be true. You may need to delve into the definition of _tcslwr_s by pressing F12 in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Check_return_wat_ _CRTIMP errno_t __cdecl _wcslwr_s(_Inout_z_cap_(_SizeInWords) wchar_t * _Str, _In_ size_t _SizeInWords);` is declaring a function called `_wcslwr_s` that takes a `wchar_t *` and `size_t` and returns an `errno_t`.  Everything that start with an underscore (except for `_Str` and `_SizeInWords`) is an attribute of the function.  For example, `__cdecl` indicates that the C calling convention should be used (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks(v=vs.80).aspx), and `_In_` indicates that the 
parameter is passed to the function.

In plain english, this function takes a string and the size of the string and returns an error code.  Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y889wzfw(v=vs.80).aspx, this function appears to convert the provided string (`_Str`) to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. And thanks for the answer at my question. upvoted and chosen as the right answer. It helped me!

Answer (score 1):

According to this MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y889wzfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx `_tcslwr_s` is a macro that maps to various functions for converting strings to lowercase depending on the definition of the `_UNICODE` (Unicode support for standard functions) and `_MBCS` (multibyte character support for standard functions) macros. 
The VB.Net equivalent would be the `.ToLower()` string method.